# Minimizing a quadratic form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I would like to minimize the following quadratic form:
$$
f(\mathbf{\theta}) = (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta}))^T \mathbf{\Sigma}({\mathbf{\theta}})^{-1}
(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})),
$$
wrt $\mathbf{\theta}$. $\mathbf{y}$ is $d$-dimensional, while $\mathbf{\theta}$ is $p$-dimensional. Generally $d \geq p$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{\theta}}$ is positive definite for any $\mathbf{\theta}$.

The partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})_{i}}{\partial \mathbf{\theta}_j}
$$
are relatively easy to estimate. On the other hand the derivatives: 
$$
\frac{\mathbf{\Sigma}({\mathbf{\theta}})_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{\theta}_k}
$$
are nearly impossible to approximate.

What I'm doing at the moment is optimizing only along $\mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})$ while treating $\mathbf{\Sigma}({\mathbf{\theta}})$ as if it was fixed. In other words I'm using steepest descent where at each step I move in the direction:
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})}{\partial \mathbf{\theta}_j}^T\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{\theta})}{\partial \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})} =
\frac{\partial \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})}{\partial \mathbf{\theta}_j}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}({\mathbf{\theta}})^{-1}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})).
$$

My question is: is there any guarantee doing this procedure converges to the minimum of $f(\mathbf{\theta})$? Thanks!

**Additional Information**

I have two possible situation:

1. Finite sample: it doesn't exist a $\mathbf{\theta}$ such that $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta})$.
2. In the limit: there is a unique $\mathbf{\theta_0}$ such that $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{\theta_0})$.

Comment: Could you provide some insight on why such problem would be different than estimating the parameters of a Gaussian (or its mixtures) and why not to tuse EM algorithm?

Comment: My problem is different from estimating the parameters of a Gaussian, because I don't want to estimate $\mathbf{\mu}$ or $\mathbf{\Sigma}({\mathbf{\theta}})$, but $\mathbf{\theta}$. Actually what I'm doing is not too different from EM, but I don't have the derivatives needed for the maximization step. Hence I need to estimate them by regression, which is simple for the mean vector, difficult for the covariance.

Comment: Well, in that case, are you able to compute an MCMC approximation with sampling? That makes the whole story stochastic, but I guess there are a lot of resources on that too.